# Scala - How to delete Keys of a Scala Map which has Null and Blank Values

Tags: scala, dictionary

I have a below Map which keys contains Null or Blank value. How to drop or filter out these key-value pair from Map using trim for blank.
Below I am trying but its not working. Kindly help.

```
val map = Map("A/B/C" -> null, "E/F/G" -> "", "F/A/D" -> " ", "M/N/O" -> 4, "N/O/P" -> 5)
val filteredMap = map.filterKeys(map(_) != null || map(_) != "".trim)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not even compilable because you are trying to use `_` but  you can't shorten expression here.
For correct result you should expand lambda expression and replace `||` to `&&`:

```
val filteredMap = map.filterKeys(
  key => Option(map(key)).exists(_.toString.trim().nonEmpty)
) 
// Map(N/O/P -> 5, M/N/O -> 4)
```

Comment: Hi Borish, It working fine for null and "" but looks like trim is not working here hence it didn't removed F/A/D -> " "

Comment: You are trimming the wrong side. No need to trim `""`. I would use `StringUtils.isNotBlank` from Commons Lang, which handles null as well as unicode whitespace.

Comment: You'll also need to `toString` if you really have numbers in there as well.

Comment: Simpler to just do `Option(map(key)).exists(_.toString.trim().nonEmpty)`

Answer (score 1):

If you mis-typed and you actually have a `Map[String,String]` then you're attempt isn't too far off. It just needs a few adjustments.

```
val map: Map[String,String] =
  Map("A/B/C" -> null, "E/F/G" -> "", "F/A/D" -> " ", "M/N/O" -> "4", "N/O/P" -> "5")

val filteredMap = map.filter(x => x._2 != null && x._2.trim != "")
```

If, on the other hand, you did not mis-type and you actually have a `Map[String,Any]` then you should fix that, but I suppose you might get away with something like this.

```
val filteredMap = map.flatMap{
  case (k:String, v:Int) => Some(k -> v)
  case (_, null) => None
  case (k:String, v:String) if v.trim.nonEmpty => Some(k -> v)
  case _ => None
}
```

But, really, you should fix that. Type `Any` is a sign that your design is going off track.

Comment: Hi @jwvh, Yes, The input is Map[String, String]